# Should "something, and therefore something" be referred to as singular or plural?

Tags: grammaticality, grammatical-number, word-usage, be

For example, if I have the sentence

> Due to the improvement of our algorithm, our model, and therefore simulation, becomes more realistic.

Should the *becomes* be instead written as *become*? Does this sentence imply that I am referring to only the model, or both the model and the simulation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say ...

> Due to the improvement of our al**g**orithm, our model, and therefore simulation, becomes more realistic.

The presence of 'therefore' and the commas makes the phrase, "and therefore simulation" parenthetical and for that reason you need the singular verb. Leave those out and you need a plural.

**Explanation**

1. *Due to the improvement of our algorithm, our model and simulation become more realistic.* [Here there are two subjects connected by 'and' and so a plural verb is necessary]
2. *Due to the improvement of our algorithm, our model (and therefore simulation) becomes more realistic.*  [In this case, and also with commas, you have made the central clause parenthetical and so there is only one subject - 'algorithm.

I prefer version 1. There is a stylistic problem with 2 that makes a rewrite preferable.

Comment: The subject is model, not algorithm. The complete first part is a prepositional phrase.

Comment: So 'Due to the improvement of our algorithm, our model and (therefore) simulation become more realistic.' is also correct? (I'm just picking up on the idiosyncrasies involved, at least at some levels).

Comment: Would it change anything if the parenthetical was plural?  As in "our model, and therefore our simulations"?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth The master and commander is ready to see you now.